# SQL Server : dynamic pivot over 5 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I'm having a very tough time trying to figure out how to do a dynamic pivot in SQL Server 2008 with multiple columns.

My sample table is as follows:

```
ID  YEAR  TYPE  TOTAL   VOLUME
DD1 2008    A   1000    10
DD1 2008    B   2000    20
DD1 2008    C   3000    30
DD1 2009    A   4000    40
DD1 2009    B   5000    50
DD1 2009    C   6000    60
DD2 2008    A   7000    70
DD2 2008    B   8000    80
DD2 2008    C   9000    90
DD2 2009    A   10000   100
DD2 2009    B   11000   110
DD2 2009    C   12000   120
```

and I'm trying the pivot it as follows:

```
ID  2008_A_TOTAL    2008_A_VOLUME   2008_B_TOTAL    2008_B_VOLUME   2008_C_TOTAL    2008_C_VOLUME   2009_A_TOTAL    2009_A_VOLUME   2009_B_TOTAL    2009_B_VOLUME   2009_C_TOTAL    2009_C_VOLUME
DD1 1000            10              2000            20              3000            30              4000            40              5000            50              6000            60
DD2 7000            70              8000            80              9000            90              10000           100             11000           110             12000           120
```

My SQL Server 2008 query is as follows to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE ATM_TRANSACTIONS 
(
 ID varchar(5),
 T_YEAR varchar(4),
 T_TYPE varchar(3), 
 TOTAL int,
 VOLUME int
);

INSERT INTO ATM_TRANSACTIONS
(ID,T_YEAR,T_TYPE,TOTAL,VOLUME)

VALUES
('DD1','2008','A',1000,10),
('DD1','2008','B',2000,20),
('DD1','2008','C',3000,30),
('DD1','2009','A',4000,40),
('DD1','2009','B',5000,50),
('DD1','2009','C',6000,60),
('DD2','2008','A',7000,70),
('DD2','2008','B',8000,80),
('DD2','2008','C',9000,90),
('DD2','2009','A',10000,100),
('DD2','2009','B',11000,110),
('DD2','2009','C',1200,120);
```

The `T_Year` column may change in the future but the `T_TYPE` column is generally know, so I'm not sure if I can use a combination of the PIVOT function in SQL Server with dynamic code?

I tried following the example here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17510.t-sql-dynamic-pivot-on-multiple-columns.aspx

but I ended up with with weird results.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In order to get the result, you will need to look at unpivoting the data in the `Total` and `Volume` columns first before applying the PIVOT function to get the final result.  My suggestion would be to first write a hard-coded version of the query then convert it to dynamic SQL.

The UNPIVOT process converts these multiple columns into rows. There are a few ways to UNPIVOT, you can use the UNPIVOT function or you can use CROSS APPLY.   The code to unpivot the data will be similar to:

```
select id, 
    col = cast(t_year as varchar(4))+'_'+t_type+'_'+col, 
    value
from ATM_TRANSACTIONS t
cross apply
(
    select 'total', total union all
    select 'volume', volume
) c (col, value);
```

This gives you data in the format:

```
+-----+---------------+-------+
| id  |      col      | value |
+-----+---------------+-------+
| DD1 | 2008_A_total  |  1000 |
| DD1 | 2008_A_volume |    10 |
| DD1 | 2008_B_total  |  2000 |
| DD1 | 2008_B_volume |    20 |
| DD1 | 2008_C_total  |  3000 |
| DD1 | 2008_C_volume |    30 |
+-----+---------------+-------+
```

Then you can apply the PIVOT function:

```
select ID, 
    [2008_A_total], [2008_A_volume], [2008_B_total], [2008_B_volume],
    [2008_C_total], [2008_C_volume], [2009_A_total], [2009_A_volume]
from
(
    select id, 
        col = cast(t_year as varchar(4))+'_'+t_type+'_'+col, 
        value
    from ATM_TRANSACTIONS t
    cross apply
    (
        select 'total', total union all
        select 'volume', volume
    ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
    max(value)
    for col in ([2008_A_total], [2008_A_volume], [2008_B_total], [2008_B_volume],
                [2008_C_total], [2008_C_volume], [2009_A_total], [2009_A_volume])
) piv;
```

Now that you have the correct logic, you can convert this to dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(cast(t_year as varchar(4))+'_'+t_type+'_'+col) 
                    from ATM_TRANSACTIONS t
                    cross apply
                    (
                        select 'total', 1 union all
                        select 'volume', 2
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by col, so, T_TYPE, T_YEAR
                    order by T_YEAR, T_TYPE, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select id, 
                    col = cast(t_year as varchar(4))+''_''+t_type+''_''+col, 
                    value
                from ATM_TRANSACTIONS t
                cross apply
                (
                    select ''total'', total union all
                    select ''volume'', volume
                ) c (col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

This will give you a result:

```
+-----+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
| id  | 2008_A_total | 2008_A_volume | 2008_B_total | 2008_B_volume | 2008_C_total | 2008_C_volume | 2009_A_total | 2009_A_volume | 2009_B_total | 2009_B_volume | 2009_C_total | 2009_C_volume |
+-----+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
| DD1 |         1000 |            10 |         2000 |            20 |         3000 |            30 |         4000 |            40 |         5000 |            50 |         6000 |            60 |
| DD2 |         7000 |            70 |         8000 |            80 |         9000 |            90 |        10000 |           100 |        11000 |           110 |         1200 |           120 |
+-----+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Fantastic. I didn't realise I needed to unpivot/cross-apply then pivot. Thanks so much.

Comment: suppppppperrrrrrrrrrb

Comment: This is great. It takes a little more work to get it going with dynamic columns, but the general idea still holds.

Comment: I want to create html tables using 1 query that will feed a jquery api a dynamic number of columns to process and found this query to be perfect for my requiremetns. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

select @stmt = isnull(@stmt + ', ', '') + 
        'sum(case when T_YEAR = ''' + T.T_YEAR + ''' and T_TYPE = ''' + T.T_TYPE + ''' then TOTAL else 0 end) as ' + quotename(T.T_YEAR + '_' +  T.T_TYPE + '_TOTAL') + ',' +
        'sum(case when T_YEAR = ''' + T.T_YEAR + ''' and T_TYPE = ''' + T.T_TYPE + ''' then VOLUME else 0 end) as ' + quotename(T.T_YEAR + '_' +  T.T_TYPE + '_VOLUME')
from (select distinct T_YEAR, T_TYPE from ATM_TRANSACTIONS) as T
order by T_YEAR, T_TYPE

select @stmt = '
    select
        ID, ' + @stmt + ' from ATM_TRANSACTIONS group by ID'

exec sp_executesql
    @stmt = @stmt
```

unfortunately, sqlfiddle.com is not working at the moment, so I cannot create an example for you.

The query created by dynamic SQL would be:

```
select
    ID,
    sum(case when T_YEAR = '2008' and T_TYPE = 'A' then TOTAL else 0 end) as 2008_A_TOTAL,
    sum(case when T_YEAR = '2008' and T_TYPE = 'A' then VOLUME else 0 end) as 2008_A_VOLUME,
    ...
from ATM_TRANSACTIONS
group by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
DECLARE @pivv NVARCHAR(MAX),@Query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @pivv=COALESCE(@pivv+',','')+ QUOTENAME(T_YEAR+'_'+T_TYPE+'_TOTAL')+','+QUOTENAME(T_YEAR+'_'+T_TYPE+'_VOLUME') from ATM_TRANSACTIONS GROUP BY T_YEAR, T_TYPE

IF ISNULL(@pivv, '')<>''
    SET @Query='SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT ID, T_YEAR+''_''+T_TYPE+''_TOTAL'' TYP, TOTAL VAL from ATM_TRANSACTIONS UNION
        SELECT ID, T_YEAR+''_''+T_TYPE+''_VOLUME'' TYP, VOLUME VAL from ATM_TRANSACTIONS 
        )x pivot (SUM(VAL) for TYP in ('+@pivv+')) as xx'

IF ISNULL(@Query, '')<>''
    EXEC (@Query)
```