# SQL Server 2008 R2: Dynamic pivot query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot-table, dynamicquery

I have the table called as sales with three columns `SalesCountry` , `SalesState` and `SalesMan` as shown below:

**Table**:

```
create table sales
(
     SalesCountry varchar(20),
     SalesState varchar(20),
     SalesMan varchar(20)
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
insert into sales values('USA','TEXAS','Mak');
insert into sales values('USA','California','Sam');
insert into sales values('Cannada','Alberta','John');
insert into sales values('Cannada','Manitoba','John');
```

Now I want to show the result as follows:

```
County      State1      State2      SalesMan1   SalesMan2
---------------------------------------------------------
USA         TEXAS       California  Mak         Sam
Cannada     Alberta     Manitoba    John        NULL
```

**Note**: The pivot query should be dynamic, which should show the columns as per the rows in the table with increment of value 1 with column name like i have shown `State1,State2` there may be `State3,State4,,,,,,n`. In my example there are only four rows, there may be more than that also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server : dynamic pivot over 5 columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657214/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-over-5-columns)

Comment: how would the final result be if we : `insert into sales values('USA','California','John');` ? would it produce SalesMan3 column ? and also, `insert into sales values('USA','Kansas','Mak');` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using PIVOT we can achieve this

```
    DECLARE @sales table 
    (
         SalesCountry varchar(20),
         SalesState varchar(20),
         SalesMan varchar(20)
    );

    insert into @sales values('USA','TEXAS','Mak');
    insert into @sales values('USA','California','Sam');
    insert into @sales values('Cannada','Alberta','John');
    insert into @sales values('Cannada','Manitoba','John');  

Select SalesCountry,MAX([1]) State1,MAX([2]) State2,MAX([Sales_1])[Sales_1],MAX([Sales_2])[Sales_2]  FROM (
select 
SalesCountry,
SalesState,
SalesMan,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY SalesCountry ORDER BY SalesCountry)RN ,
'Sales'+'_'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY SalesCountry ORDER BY SalesCountry) AS VARCHAR)RNN
    FROM @sales
    )T
PIVOT (MAX(SalesState) for RN IN ([1],[2]))P
PIVOT (MAX(SalesMan) for RNN IN ([Sales_1],[Sales_2]))PP
GROUP BY PP.SalesCountry
```

Comment: This assumes there will only ever be two salesmen per country.   Read the last "note" in the original question.

Comment: Yes, we should.   Just like in the duplicate question I flagged.