# Columns names in new table from query. UNPIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table:

[image: Table]

I want use UNPIVOT to create table, where CategoryNames rows are columns names.
So, now I can just write this as

```
SELECT Year, Seafood, Meat/Poultry, [...]
FROM [...] UNPIVOT(...) AS Example
```

but I don't want write every row manually as column name, so is any option to use

```
SELECT CategoryName
FROM Pods
```

query result to create them automatically.

For this example its only 8 row, but with bigger count this could be very helpful.

[image: How I want my final table to look]

Comment: *"I want use UNPIVOT to create table, where CategoryNames rows are columns names"* That isn't an `UNPIVOT`, that's a `PIVOT`. `UNPIVOT` transforms columns to rows, and `PIVOT` does the opposite (via aggregation).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657214/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-over-5-columns